# Как написать событие нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android

Осваиваю `Android studio java` - хочу написать андроид приложение.

1. Пока не пойму, как написать событие нажатия на кнопку
2. Как установить библиотеку `AppCompat v7`

Comment: Советую начать с первого урока, там человек все подробно обьясняет. 
 В том числе и с кнопками. https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html . И прежде чем писать вопрос на стековерфлоу стоит погуглить. Поверьте, будет масса информации. А когда уже действительно будет сложный вопрос - милости просим.

Comment: я гуглил, сразу не понять что к чему и что где писать к примеру  на php понятней

Answer (score 1):

**Установка** `AppCompat v7`

Заходим в `build.gradle (module:app)`
В секцию `dependencies` добавляем

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

**Установка события на кнопку (два способа)**

```
Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Действие при клике
                }
            });
```

Через реализацию интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            // Действие при клике
            break;
    }
}
```

Есть еще способы, но для новичка этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ         Вставил этот код Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Действие при клике
                }
            }); в Mainactivityjava выскочили следующие ошибки C:\Users\Developer\AndroidStudioProjects\netFace\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:16: AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Выложи разметку

Comment: @АнатолийКолосков у вас в разметке должна быть кнопка с айди - button

Comment: дабавил В секцию dependencies 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' в mainactivity.jva в разделе import видит только import android.support.v4.app.*; то есть v7 не видит.